# Pacman: opencascade74 and opencascade are in conflict while upgrading

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, pacman, cad

when I run `sudo pacman -Syu` pacman throws this error:

```
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 core is up to date
 extra is up to date
 community-testing is up to date
 community is up to date
 multilib is up to date
:: Starting full system upgrade...
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...
error: unresolvable package conflicts detected
error: failed to prepare transaction (conflicting dependencies)
:: opencascade74 and opencascade are in conflict
```

I tried to clear cache with `sudo pacman -Sc` but error remains

When I try to remove `opencascade` package but:

```
sudo pacman -R opencascade
checking dependencies...
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: removing opencascade breaks dependency 'opencascade' required by freecad

How can I get around this error to upgrade my system ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it ignoring `freecad` first:

```
sudo pacman -Syu --ignore freecad
```

and then run upgrade without ignore flag `sudo pacman -Syu`:

```
[sudo] password for john:
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 core is up to date
 extra is up to date
 community-testing is up to date
 community is up to date
 multilib is up to date
:: Starting full system upgrade...
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...
:: opencascade74 and opencascade are in conflict. Remove opencascade? [y/N]
```

Confirm with yes

Now you have upgraded your system without any conflicts.

---

**BTW:** Bug report has been already made: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/68673